# Autogenerate forms from django rest framework serializer outside of API browser

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

If I link a django form with a model, I can easily render the corresponding HTML form using
{% crispy form %}.  How can I do something similar in the django-rest-framework? How do I take a serialized model and render the corresponding HTML form on some webpage? I am trying to not use the API browser form. Rather, I want to generate that same form elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form directly from a model by using a [model form factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function). Pass this form to the template and you should be set.